# Rate app reminder for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, marketplace, rate

I'm a new developer and I want to know a good way to create an app rate reminder to my WP app. The reminder should stop remind if the users clicks "okay" or checks the box "don't show this again"

I've searched a bit and found the Telerik plugins, but, they cost?

Is there any other easy code to implement instead?

Comment: Be sure to check out this page "Improve app ratings with a rating reminder" easy to use just drag and drop, also tracks other stuff such as how many runs the app has had etc...:-) [http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Improve-app-ratings-with-a-6139caa5#content]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show simple MessageBox (OK, Cancel) and if user clicked OK - show MarketplaceReviewTask. For example:

```
        if (MessageBox.Show("Rate this app?", "Some title", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            var a = new MarketplaceReviewTask();
            a.Show();
        }
```

Also check [this article](http://roybott.com/blog/getting-ratings-for-your-wp7-app.html).

Comment: Nice article. Gave +1 for the article